# Hibernate: Is it possible to find out which eagerly loaded collections are actually used?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, persistence

I have the suspicion that some performance problems in one of our applications is caused by too much eager loading of some associations by hibernate, which might be resolved by switching to lazy loading. Unfortunately it is quite difficult to track how and when the associations are actually used - and much less how often they are used "on average". Are there some tools (hibernate logging options?) which help to decide which of the eagerly loaded associations should be better lazily loaded and / or switched to other [fetching strategies](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html/ch20.html#performance-fetching)?

For instance I could imagine a tool that says for logs for each hibernate session how many objects of each class were loaded and how much of them have actually been accessed by the application, or even generates some statistics about that. Of course, in the end only a load test can decide what is better, but this might give you some ideas what to try. Or perhaps there are even better tools out there.

Comment: If the collections are in the model, then, most likely they are used somewhere in your code and all of them are being accessed at some point, as typically you would not persist unwanted data. So only the "on average" information would be useful. Isn't other way arround, that you should start with all the relationships being lazy and then only convert to eager the ones for each it makes sense? If batch fetching is enabled on lazy relationship the eager one is not much faster.

Answer (score 1):

Hibernate doesn't support any LAZY initialization statistics, because it only provides a framework, but in the end, it's the application developer responsibility to decide how to use it for satisfying his project requirements.

[EAGER fetching is a code smell](http://vladmihalcea.com/eager-fetching-is-a-code-smell/). Most often it’s used for simplicity sake without considering the long-term performance penalties. The fetching strategy should never be the entity mapping responsibility.

Each business use case has different entity load requirements and therefore the fetching strategy should be delegated to each individual query.

The best statistics you can get is to simply [log all SQL statements](https://github.com/ttddyy/datasource-proxy) and decide if the executed queries are needed for fulfilling each specific request requirements.

My advice is to favor LAZY associations, and use query-based fetch directive whenever you need to load some LAZY associations.